# Auto forecasting vs hierarchical forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'am a new data scientist in my company, and we don't have expert to guide me, so please i really need for your help and guidness for this problem.

I need to forecast sales for many products and i have found two approches (hierarchical forecast that requires many models for each node in the tree of hierarchy), and the auto forecast when i try for differents models and select the best one. So to resume the topic, i have two main questions

My first question is, if we can have an auto forecast, why would we do a hierarchical forecast that requires high computation cost.

My second question is about deployment. what's your recommandations to deploy this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **My first question is, if we can have an auto forecast, why would we do a hierarchical forecast that requires high computation cost.**

Hierarchical forecasting from an applied perspective would be very important if you need all your forecasts at different levels to be 'coherent' and it can increase forecast accuracy. For example, if you are forecasting for products which go to multiple countries which have distribution centers which are assigned stores you then have the ability to forecast at just the whole item level or all the way down to the most granular level which is the store.

So if you want forecasts at all levels you have a few options:

1. Forecast at the *highest* level and disaggregate based on rules down to the lower levels
2. Forecast at the *lowest* level and aggregate up
3. Forecast in the middle and aggregate up and disaggregate down
4. Forecast at *every* level
5. Forecast at *every* level but adjust it using a hierarchical approach

Every approach has strengths and weaknesses which the hierarchical tries to overcome, for example if you forecast at each level then when you hand off your item level forecast to the financial department and your DC level forecast to supply chain they actually won't add up.  This is where the 'coherent' part comes in.  Hierarchical forecasting will try to rectify differences at different levels so everything adds up.  Additionally, we can leverage forecasts at potentially more stable levels which can increase accuracy at the lower levels.

So really it just depends, do you need forecasts at every level?  If not I would just do the auto route or better yet use the several models and hand them off to an ensemble method.

2. **My second question is about deployment. what's your recommandations to deploy this.**

What do you need it to do? Do you need a graphical interface for it?  Do you just need numbers pushed to a database? How many items? What's the update frequency? I mean, if you got like 20 items then just run it on your laptop and push it to an excel spread sheet.  If you got 1 million then you'll probably need some distributed solution.

Comment: thank you so much for this details, for the first question i still have problem, for exemple, if i have the tree of all levels of hierarchy, so i can just apply an auto forecast, and for every node aven if it's about the most granular level, i call the time series of this node and run my auto forecast. So if i can forecast any node in any level, why would i need the hierarchical forecast.

Comment: @Taylor you can forecast at any level BUT if you look at your forecasts at the most granular level and sum them up to the highest level it will not (usually) equal your forecast at the highest level.  Therefore they are not 'coherent'.  So we rectify that with a hierarchical technique.  If you don't care about that consistency then you are good to just use the auto forecast at whatever level you want!  Really it comes to play when you are dealing with different departments who care about different things ie Finance caring about future item revenue and Supply Chain caring about DC planning.

Comment: @ Tylerr. i wille take your example: "if you look at your forecasts at the most granular level and sum them up to the highest level it will not (usually) equal your forecast at the highest level." . In my mind, i can imagine that i can use autoforecast just to forecast the highest level when i need it without using the two most granular

Comment: @Taylor if you only care about the highest level then that is fine.  If you care about all levels and you need them to all add up then it might not be fine.  Like you could have a forecast for the item level be 10k for the year but at the dc level when you sum up the forecasts to the item level it could be 7k.  If you just need to produce numbers for the highest level then hierarchical probably won't do much for you, if you just need it for the most granular level it could give you a performance boost over just forecasting the granular level.

Comment: @ Tylerr, may be i was not clear, sorry,I didn't mean that, i mean that if  i will prepare all the time series of every level and every item, and after that, i select the level and the item (this can be in high level  as it can be in the lowest one) and i apply my autoforecast to have my forcast values.

Comment: @ Tylerr. For example, if i have this hierarchy : A->(A1,A2), i can imagine that we can do it simply. If i want to forecast (A) i just call its time series and apply my autoforecast, and if i want to have the forecast of (A1) i call the time series of A1 and apply y autoforecast, and the same thing for A2. Thats why i still not understand why using hierarchical forecast in some cases, because in the case abouve, i see that i can do it with autoforecast. Hope that it's more clear this time. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: @Taylor , yes but A =/= A1 + A2 when we forecast them separately without applying some hierarchical approach such as optimal reconciliation.  Highly recommend you check out chapter 10 of this book (and really all chapters for that matter): https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html . If you don't care about that consistency then don't worry about using it!  If you want to use this specific method to fix the issue then you would still need to forecast at each level, it itself is not a 'forecast' rather a 'forecast adjustment'.

Comment: I suggest using ESM (exponential smoothing) in addition, possibly combining multiple predictions. They are easy to use and in my experience are reasonably accurate.

Comment: @ Tylerr, thank you for the chapter , i read it , but if i understand the autoforecast, i think that if you want to have the forecast of A in the hierarchy (A->A1+A2), you don't need to forecast A1 and A2, you just apply an autoforcast on A (to have the best model of A), so even if A=/=A1+A2, it dosn't matter, because in auto forecast i will have the best model and the forecast of (A) without care about A1 and A2, i mean it will be just like ( A+best model of A = Forecast of A).

Comment: @ Tylerr,  that is why i dont understand the raison why we need for hierarchical forecast, because i see that with autoforecast, i can do it for any ( Aij ) without care about others (Aij+best model of Aij = forecast of Aij).

Comment: @Taylor, yeah you can forecast at whatever level you want whenever you want.  But if you want your forecasts to make sense at every level then by definition they need to be pretty close to each other as you look at the sums of each level right?  For example if at your most granular level it is really intermittent then you are likely to get pretty bad forecasts which could be 50% different than your total forecast, which is completely unacceptable if you are interested in forecasts at all levels.  If you truly only care about A and don't have to send out other levels, then just forecast A.

Comment: @Taylor just imagine this:  You give a presentation to your CEO and project company revenue to be 1 billion based on company level sales (a single time series).  Then you give a presentation to your finance department who looks at item level sales, but when you look at the item level (n number of time series for n number of items) forecast summed up it is 700 million.  This is the issue at hand.  If you are only giving the presentation to finance at item level then don't worry about this difference.

Comment: @ Tylerr, aaah okay!, i understand now! thank you somuch, i still just have a last question about the base forecasts. i think that i can do them by an autoforecast, but i don't know haw to deploye them, could i use a built-in models which will be trained at the time i call the quantity to forecast and give the result. or i have to deploye models that is trained continiously in cycle of ML. Hope the question is clear

Comment: @Taylor depends on scale and a few other things.  if you can do the training in a reasonable amount of time then you could just re-run it each time.  An issue of that could be unstable forecasts each time you run.For example one month a seasonal model could win and the next a non-seasonal (assuming it is choosing the best one).The other option you mention would be online learning and that would really be more for like stock trading or dealing with website data.IDK what your situation falls into but it would be way more difficult to deploy this that running it monthly on your laptop!